# Aws Wrangler giving not implemented error: impossible to query aws athena

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to query AWS Athena with aws wrangler, but it's always giving me 'NotImplementedError: dictionary<values=int32, indices=int32, ordered=0>'. Currently the wrangler package I'm using is 2.17.0 and I've tried both python 3.10.8 and 3.9.15.

To reproduce:

```
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="eu-central-1")

def download_all_matches():
    query = "SELECT * FROM database"
    df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(query, database="db",categories=["x","y"])

df = download_all()
```

The issue seems to be with pyarrow, however, I've tried to use other packages in addition to the basic package (8.0.0) conda installs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the trick was to not specify the columns (read_sql_query(... categories=[]). In my understanding some of the previous versions of Wrangler demanded, or at least worked with, specifying the categories or columns.